# How to implement popover(similar to bootstrap) using angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to implement popover as in Bootstrap, in my angular app, for logout function.

[image: logout]

Is there any material component, for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [That's why Google is here](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview).

Comment: Hi. i saw tooltip. but it vanihes if i move my cursor.. how to configure it to change background color and stay, even if mouse moves..

Comment: Several solutions, you seem to have tried none ? You can do it with CSS, the CDK, a directive, and a lot of other solutions.